# How to determine if a screen is running jobs without attaching to it?

Tags: linux, shell-script, zsh, gnu-screen

I wrote a `zsh` script that launches many screen sessions and runs a different command in each of them. When the script is executed there are 72 screens in total, so checking if a `job` is finished or not manually is a huge time consuming task. Can I run some separate script that will check if the screen sessions have running jobs or not and kill the session when there are no running jobs. Do you have any ideas? I could not think of any method to reliably check what happened in all of the screen sessions, thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you execute the screen sessions? Isn't it possible that the command which is run in the session terminates the session itself?

Answer (score 1):

I could imagine that the *output logging* feature of screen could help You accomplish this (see the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen) for details). You could produce output logs of Your sessions and check them to see if Your jobs have finished.

Or You could check the tree of running processes (e.g. using `pstree`) to see if the shells within the screen sessions still have running children or not. However, I could imagine that parsing the output of `pstree` in a script is cumbersome and error-prone, so You might actually want to use the kernel interfaces (to get the running processes tree) for that.

Comment: Thanks, the output logging feature is nice, but I would like to terminate screens which sit idle automatically, preferentially with the aid of another script.

Comment: Well, how would You determine if a screen is *idle*? Screens whose children terminate terminate themselves. If the children don't terminate, I don't think there's any clean (and reliable!) way of determining *idleness*.